# Hadoop only connecting on localhost

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop

I am trying to connect a data node to my name node. 
It seems the name node does not accept connections when its raw IP is used.
If I try to connect via telnet on the name node host in this way

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 54310
```

it works but if I try (always on the name node) withs its own raw IP

```
telnet 192.168.1.7 54310
```

it doesn't

I am running Hadoop on Ubunt and the ufw status is inactive

Comment: In your etc/hosts change it to look like 192.168.1.7  myhostname. Make sure in core-site.xml fs.default.name' value=hdfs://myhostname:8020

Answer (score 3, accepted):

run `netstat -tuplen` and make sure the name node is listening on `192.168.1.7` and not `127.0.0.1`

If it **is** listening on `127.0.0.1` check `/etc/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml` and see what the `fs.default.name` is

```
  <property>
    <name>fs.default.name</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:8020</value>
  </property>
```

If it is a **hostname** make sure that the `/etc/hosts` does not have a hostname entry of `127.0.0.1`

Comment: Thanks. I removed/replace all 127.0.0.1 entries from the hosts file and restart all services in the ambari server. Works fine!